# Convert nearest time value to exact hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I have a table which has hour level records but they are not exact 24 hours like 1:00 pm , 2:00 pm etc. instead I have more than 24 data points like 2:18 , 2:38, 3:10, 3:45 and so on.

In my final dataset, I want only 24 data points with exact hours where I am planning to have data points most close to the coming hour as that exact hour and delete other. Refer attached images for clear reference.

Original Dataset:

[image]

whereas i want final data-set to be like

Final Expect:

[image]

So, basically I might have multiple data point for an hour range and I have to set the nearest one with the next exact hour and deleting other.

Any lead on this as what approach I should take in. Any method to achieve the same?

Comment: What is the data type of the time column, and what version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Data type is time(7) and I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio (12.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are another approaches for archiving this, but mine is as following:-

- Use `dateadd` function for adding the extra minutes for reaching the next hour.
- Use `Where` clause for selecting only the desired output via using `Min`
  function.

**Demo:-**

*DDL & DML*

```
Create table Test (
                    [Date] date , 
                    [time] time(7), 
                    col1 char (1),
                    col2 char (1) , 
                    col3 char(1)
                )
go
insert into Test values ('02/02/2017' , '1:15' , 'a' , 'b' , 'c')
insert into Test values ('02/02/2017' , '1:35' , 'w' , 'e' , 'r')
insert into Test values ('02/02/2017' , '2:16' , 'q' , 'w' , 'e')
insert into Test values ('02/02/2017' , '3:48' , 'z' , 'x' , 'c')
insert into Test values ('02/02/2017' , '3:58' , 'b' , 'n' , 'm')
go
select * from Test
```

Result:-

[image]

*Query*

```
select [Date] , 
        dateadd(minute,abs(datepart(minute,[time]) - 60),[time]) as [time],
        col1 , col2 , col3
from test
where 
    datepart(hour,[time]) 
in
(
    select 
    datepart(hour,[time]) 
    from Test
    group by datepart(hour,[time]) 

)
AND 
    abs(datepart(minute,[time]) - 60)
in 
(
    select 
    min(abs(datepart(minute,[time]) - 60)) 
    from Test
    group by datepart(hour,[time]) 
)
```

Result:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this ahmed. It really looks helpful and try to leverage the same for my scenario. Just one mention here will this piece take into consideration the fact that 23rd hour estimation will eventually go for next day. SO, date needs to be updated accordingly. For example, the data point for 02/02/2017 for 23:48 need to be estimated to 00:00 03/02/2017. So, accordingly date needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), and [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) to get the next round hour:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [Date],
           DATEADD(MINUTE, 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, [time]), [time]) [Time],
           col1,
           col2,
           col3,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(HOUR, [time]) ORDER BY Date, Time DESC) rn
    FROM Test
)

SELECT CASE WHEN [Time] = '00:00:00' THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) ELSE [Date] END [Date],
       [Time],
       col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Results:

```
Date            Time        col1    col2    col3
02.02.2017      02:00:00    w       e       r
02.02.2017      03:00:00    q       w       e
02.02.2017      04:00:00    b       n       m
```

Comment: Thanks ZOhar.  It really looks helpful and try to leverage the same for my scenario. Just one mention here will this piece take into consideration the fact that 23rd hour estimation will eventually go for next day. SO, date needs to be updated accordingly. For example, the data point for 02/02/2017 for 23:48 need to be estimated to 00:00 03/02/2017. So, accordingly date needs to be updated

Comment: Just add a case. I've edited my answer to include it.